# How to delete unwanted blank page in parallel text?

Tags: formatting, page-breaking, blank-page, parallel, gregorio

I'm compiling a bilingual Gregorio document, and a couple of pages into the booklet I use the \parallel package so that chant on an odd page continue onto the next odd page (and same for even pages). The problem is that when I compile, there's an extra blank page just before the \parallel pages (please forgive such a large chunk of code).

Thank you in advance for your response, 
Carlos

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}
\usepackage[papersize={6in,9in},top={15mm},headheight={10mm},headsep={5mm},left={17.5mm},right={17.5mm},bottom={15mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{parallel}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[CO]{{\color{red}Ordinarium}}
\fancyhead[CE]{{\color{red}Ordinario}}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C,R,L]{}

\begin{document}

%%...

\newpage

\begin{center}

\textbf{\large{Himno}}

\end{center}

\normalsize{\textit{\color{red}El tono para el himno} Te lucis ante terminum, {\textit{\color{red}o}} Christe, qui, splendor et dies, {\textit{\color{red}o bien}}  Jesu, redemptor sæculi, {\textit{\color{red} (todos con traducción) cambia según los Tiempos y las Fiestas}} p.}

\begin{center}

\textbf{\large{Salmodia}}

\end{center}

\normalsize{\textit{\color{red}En los domingos y solemnidades, después de las I Vísperas, se dicen los salmos 4 y 133(134),} p. {\textit{\color{red} ; después de las II Vísperas, el salmo 90(91),}} p. 

\vspace{3mm}

\textit{\color{red}Durante las octavas de Navidad y de Pascua, se reza cualquiera de las Completas del domingo.}

\vspace{3mm}

\textit{\color{red}Los demás días se dicen los salmos correspondientes al día de la semana. Puede, sin embargo, sustituirse siempre la salmodia del día por la del domingo, sobre todo para comodidad de quienes rezan las Completas de memoria. En este caso, puede tomarse cualquiera de las Completas del domingo.}}

\begin{center}

\vspace{1mm}

\textbf{\large{Lectura breve}}

\end{center}

\textit{\color{red}Después de la salmodia, se hace la lectura breve, que se toma del mismo lugar del que se han tomado los salmos.  Después de dice el responsorio breve.}

\begin{center}

\textbf{\large{Responsorio breve}}

\end{center}

\textit{\color{red}Durante el año:}

\gregorioscore{responsorioduranteelano}

%here the blank page appears
\begin{Parallel}[p]{}{}

\ParallelLText{

\textit{\color{red}Tempore adventus:}

\gregorioscore{responsoriumadventus}

\vspace{5mm}

\textit{\color{red}Tempore Quadragesimæ:}

\gregorioscore{responsoriumquadr}

\vspace{5mm}

\normalsize{\textit{\color{red}Per triduum paschae, in loco responsorio dicitur graduale} Christus factus est. {\textit{\color{red}Feria quinta in coena domini:}}}

\gregorioscore{gradualejueves}
}

\ParallelRText{
\textit{\color{red}Tiempo de Adviento:}


\gregorioscore{responsorioadviento}

\vspace{5mm}

\textit{\color{red}Tiempo de Cuaresma:}

\gregorioscore{responsorioquar}

\vspace{5mm}

\normalsize{\textit{\color{red}Durante el Santo Triduo Pascual, en lugar del responsorio se canta el gradual} Christus factus est. {\textit{\color{red}Jueves Santo:}}}

\gregorioscore{gradualjueves}
}

\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

[image: Image 1] [image: Image 2]

Comment: Since I don't have the "music" files (I don't know what kind of files it are), I can't reproduce the error. But I think you need to write `\begin{Parallel}[p]{\textwidth}{\textwidth}`. Because the `parallel` package says it's a feature if you leave the `{}` empty.

Comment: Thank you @Simon for your comment, however I've just tried that and it still leaves the blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't reproduce your example, but you are right: the environment `parallel` seems to start on a new page. So if your *Himno* fills the first page just, then an empty page will appear right before the parallel text starts.

Maybe you can have at least one line empty by using `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}`or `\enlargethispage{2\baselineskip}` on the last page before a parallel environment.

Besides this: using color in a parallel environment isn't a good idea, *except* you swap `\usepackage{parallel}` for `\usepackage{pdfcolparallel}`, the latter fixing some issues with the colour stack and the parallel package.

Besides all that: Your pages look beautifully.

---

**EDIT:**

If you comment out the line `\enlargethispage...`, you'll get an empty page:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, ngerman, parskip=half, twoside=true, Verbose]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext, babel, pdfcolparallel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[Verbose]{parallel}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[5]
\enlargethispage{2cm}

\begin{Parallel}[p]{}{}
  \ParallelLText{\color{red}
    \blinddocument
  }
  \ParallelRText{\color{blue}
    \blinddocument
  }

\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```